# FieldDoesNotExist: product_purchase_categories has no field named 'None' ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am trying to add ManyToMany relationships to an instance in and Django continues to throw a strange error.  I am hoping someone has seen this before or may have some insight into why I am seeing this.  Below are the two models I am working with.  My product model is quite large so I slimmed it down.  The other fields should not have any relevance.

```
class baseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class category(baseModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="",blank=True)
short_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="",blank=True)
external_id = models.IntegerField(help_text="",blank=True,null=True)
sales_channel = models.ForeignKey('sales_channel',related_name = 'sales_categories',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
purchase_channel = models.ForeignKey('purchase_channel',related_name = 'purchase_categories',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='child_categories',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
category_level = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

def _product_count(self):
   "Number of Products"
   product_count = self.category_products.count()
   return product_count
product_count = property(_product_count)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name# + ' ('+str(self.product_count)+')'


class product(baseModel):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The title of the product.")
additional_details = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Additional product information provided by the supplier",null=True,blank=True,)
description = models.TextField(max_length=4000, help_text="")
# ...
purchase_channel = models.ForeignKey('purchase_channel',related_name = 'products',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
purchase_external_id = models.IntegerField(help_text="external_id from purchasing channel",null=True,blank=True)
purchase_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2, help_text="pruchase cost of the product.", blank=True, null=True)
purchase_categories = models.ManyToManyField(category,related_name = 'categories_products',blank=True)
# ...
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Below is what I ran in shell.  Grabbed a product, grabbed a category, tried to add said category to product and then receive the following error.

```
In [44]: prod = product.objects.get(id=2705)

In [45]: prod
Out[45]: <product: Embassy&trade; Italian Stone&trade; Design Genuine Leather Backpack/Cart>

In [46]: cat = category.objects.get(id=324)

In [47]: cat
Out[47]: <category: Accessories>

In [48]: prod.purchase_categories.add(cat)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py in get_field(self, field_name)
    565             # field map.
--> 566             return self.fields_map[field_name]
    567         except KeyError:

KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FieldDoesNotExist                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-f73a74ace2f4> in <module>()
----> 1 prod.purchase_categories.add(cat)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    496             return self
    497 
--> 498         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
    499 
    500     def _get_set_deprecation_msg_params(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __init__(self, instance)
    779             self.reverse = reverse
    780 
--> 781             self.source_field = self.through._meta.get_field(self.source_field_name)
    782             self.target_field = self.through._meta.get_field(self.target_field_name)
    783 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py in get_field(self, field_name)
    566             return self.fields_map[field_name]
    567         except KeyError:
--> 568             raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
    569 
    570     def get_base_chain(self, model):

FieldDoesNotExist: product_purchase_categories has no field named 'None'
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you "makemigrations" and "migrate" ?

Comment: Yes. Like 5 times to double check. I also changed the field name on Product and migrated again to make sure there wasn’t some weird conflict or something

Comment: The only thing I could find was someone mentioning that it may be due to duplicate instance “name” on the related field (category), but it was not marked at the correct answer and honestly didn’t make sense. I will regularly be saving categories that hold the same name.

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem then, it seems to be ok :\
try this line instead of add:
"prod.purchase_categories = category.objects.filter(id=324)"

Comment: I think the problem must be somewhere else, in the models declaration

Comment: prod.purchase_categories = category.objects.filter(id=324)

TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use purchase_categories.set() instead.

prod.purchase_categories.set(category.objects.filter(id=324))

FieldDoesNotExist: product_purchase_categories has no field named 'None'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164767/discussion-between-beautiful-drifter-and-nmc).

Comment: On the product or category declaration?